Converting general formatted date/time into real date/time in excel
I have a data set exported from Oracle to excel.  There is a column with what appears as Date/Time in the format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.
However, it is not a number.   It is formatted as general. No amount of converting has worked yet.  I need to get it to convert to a standard date/time format in excel.
On the Home tab, under the "Number" Section, in the dropdown it indicates "General" No Specific Format.  All the other choices in the drop down show the exact same format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.
I have tried:
Right Clicking the cells and selecting "Format Cells" and changing the Category.
Using the replace function to replace the "/" with "/" or replace them with "-".
DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"MM/DD/YYYY"))
TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:SS"))
DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"MM/DD/YYYY"))+TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:SS"))
VALUE(A1)
DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)
DATEVALUE(A1)
"text to columns" on the data tab.
Removing the time.  =LEFT(A1,10) but that cuts the year short by 1 digit.
Removing the time.  =LEFT(A1,11) this gives the appearance without the time, but it is still not a date.
Converting the cells to text then doing a VALUE function or DATEVALUE function.
Converting the cells to text then doing removing the time then doing a value function or DATEVALUE function.
Nothing seems to work.  All I get is a value error or no change.
Time settings on the computer are UTC-06:00 Central Time (US & Canada) Language Region is English (United States) Regional format is "Recommended"
I have searched a lot of forums and watched several videos.  Nothing seems to be working.
enter image description here
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 17:21:52‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 17:25:01‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬


Can you copy paste a few examples.  There must be some non printable character that is keeping the conversion from happening.  Makw sure you copy/paste from the data you have and not retype it, as stated there is probably something in the string that cannot be seen/converted.

Transaction Date
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 17:21:52‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 17:25:01‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 15:39:38‬
‭08/01/2024 08:59:35‬
‭08/01/2024 08:59:35‬
‭08/01/2024 17:03:02‬
‭08/01/2024 08:58:20‬
‭08/01/2024 16:02:48‬
‭08/01/2024 17:32:35‬
‭08/01/2024 17:38:18‬
‭08/01/2024 17:10:04‬
‭08/01/2024 15:58:37‬

Please [edit] the post to include the data and do not use comments to add details.

I am trying to add the paste like you suggested but it only wants to add it as a picture??

It will not allow me to copy and paste a sample of the data outside the comments.

You have a non printable character at the end of each string.  Try =--LEFT(A1,19) and format the cell as desired.

That didn't work either.  I still get the #VALUE! error.

to post just text in the question edit, Right click and paste as plain text what you copied from excel.

I did.  It came through just like it did in the comments.

Apply this formula to your values: =--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,UNICHAR(8237),""),UNICHAR(8236),""). Then format that decimal number as a date.

Your data has a non printable character at the end and beginning of the string:

So use MID to get the data before and after them:
=--MID(A1,2,19)

and format as desired.


I have tried that and it doesn't change.   I tried changing the formatting after doing that and it doesn't change.

The use of =--MID(A2,2,19) solved the issue.  Thank you so much Scott.  And, thank you for your patience.
